# When I copy an iso image to a disk without filesystem, how is the size metadata stored?

Tags: files

I can copy iso or image files to a system disk with `cp /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb` or `cp file.image /dev/sdb`.

In this case, is the size of the result stored as metadata on /dev/sdb?

Comment: The command examples you give don't do what you think they do, and can actually damage your system. Don't use them.

Comment: The meta data is within the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a filesystem is stored in the filesystem.  (For most filesystems.  I guess because it determines the size of structures like FATs or free space bitmaps).

I don't believe there's a generic tool, it's just not that common to need it.   But `isosize` will report the size of an ISO9660 filesystem.  I have a feeling this tool is provided because CDROM's or maybe just CD-R's have a habit of returning I/O errors at/beyond the end.